# Can I flag a whole comment thread?

Tags: discussion

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28291195/2069064) yesterday with what I thought was an OK answer: I gave OP fixes for his syntax issues, and suggested that he explore a particular library for solving his problem better.

This morning I wake up to FOURTEEN comments on this answer, most of which have nothing to do with the answer and devolved into a non-constructive argument between the OP and two other commenters.

Each individual comment isn't necessarily bad enough that I would flag it as unconstructive or offensive - but as a whole it is. Should I just flag all of them? None of them?

Side question - can I turn off notifications to this question? I really could not care less where that thread keeps going.

Comment: Just flag the post and explain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, my answer you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flag your own post, use the 'Other' option and request that a moderator clean up the comments.

A sample flag message to have comments cleaned up that I used in the past:

> The comment thread on this post has derailed entirely, and should probably be cleaned up. Can a moderator remove all the comments?

You cannot opt out from notifications from a post, no. You could ask the commenters nicely to take the discussion elsewhere (like a chatroom).