# Do we need a functionality to mute or "unfollow" a comment thread?

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63930337/three-js-how-to-slowly-rotate-a-mesh-until-it-reaches-a-specific-value/63946834?noredirect=1#comment114154241_63946834) in September 17th. What followed were dozens of requests for additional help, which have still not stopped as of today (October 27th). Comments like:

- "I still haven't figured it out"
- "it hasn't worked so far"
- "could you please help me?"

[image]

I said a few times that I can't help any further, but the messages don't stop. It's led to a very frustrating experience because I keep getting notifications on my phone at night (due to timezone differences) from someone I can no longer help. I don't want to turn off all notifications, just any new ones from that specific thread. I've even contemplated deleting the answer.

I'm not asking to mute a user, [as this question suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260581/add-ability-to-ignore-users/315968#315968), since maybe I can still help with other questions in the future. [This answer suggests flagging for moderator cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285237/can-i-flag-a-whole-comment-thread), but the OP can always come back and comment again, triggering further notifications. I'd like to have the agency to mute that thread without having to do a flag write-up. I'm practically getting spammed and there's nothing I can do about it.

#### Edit:

Members have suggested that this is a duplicate of [Disabling notifications for a question (it's 10 years old)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375410/disabling-notifications-for-a-question-its-10-years-old). But that question only outlines a **second** reason why this feature would be useful. It doesn't provide a solution because the answer agrees that we need this "unfollow" comment thread functionality, which doesn't yet exist. That's why my question has the `[feature-request]` tag. That answer also says that locking and dissociation are not good options because they don't achieve the desired result:

- Locking prevents further constructive comments.
- Dissociation means you'd lose reputation from your answer.

### Edit 2:

Well, looks like my request of adding a "mute thread" button was found to be a duplicate. Most suggested answers say I have to write up a flag and ask a mod to handle it for me, so that's what I'll keep doing. It just seems that nobody addressed the feature-request itself and [its merits for multiple scenarios](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375418/2608515). It would be much simpler to just silently unfollow comments without bothering mods for intervention or needing to delete conversations. Discourse.org forums handle this wonderfully, with no friction whatsoever:

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure we have a dupe for that FR. Just too lazy looking it up now,

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: @HansPassant That "chameleon question" post doesn't address my issue. This isn't about a question that keeps changing over time. It's about me saying I'm unable to help further, but the OP keeps coming back twice a week to repeatedly ask "can you help me?". Chat rooms, helping further, and asking nicely don't apply to my situation.

Comment: @toolic Thank you for that link! That person outlines *another* reason why the "unfollow post" feature would be very helpful. However, it does not answer my question, since only answer suggests that my "mute notifications" request would be the best solution to solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but [the only answer in that post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375418/2608515) clearly explains why disassociation has undesired effects that wouldn't happen if there was a new "unfollow thread" feature. If you scroll down, the [answer that supports disasociation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375419/2608515) is at **-18 points**!

Comment: I am very opposed to adding a "mute" feature. Telling you to flag for moderator attention is not a "workaround"—it is *the solution*. A "mute" feature would only solve the problem for you, leaving the mess for everyone else who runs across it, and, furthermore, letting the user go on annoying others in a similar manner. Flagging for moderator attention gets a moderator to step in and solve the problem once and for all. Remember that this is not a discussion site or a chat forum. Ignoring users isn't the answer. We're building a library of Q&A for others that will stand the test of time.

Comment: I'm the user who asked that question that definitely is _not_ a duplicate of this one. I just got an answer to an 11 year old question about SQL, which has had many correct answers and one accepted for the last 11 years, but someone felt it was a great idea to add yet another answer.

Comment: @Petruza Yeah, I tried to explain that your question is not the same scenario, but a second justifiable reason to have a "mute" button. Sadly, I couldn't stop the close train once it got rolling. Cody Gray above is the only one who addressed the question, although I disagree because I didn't want to have all the comments deleted by a mod, since some of them provided valuable context. I still think that a mute button is justified in your scenario too. As a contributor, you should be trusted with the agency to choose when you no longer want notifications without deleting the whole thread.

Comment: "*because I keep getting notifications on my phone at night*" - Your SO app actually notifies you? personally i consider it a win if it can actually open a page, let alone them fancy-pants notification features

Comment: @TheGeneral I was actually notified on my phone just now about your comment, haha! I use iOS, not sure if you're using Android. Unfortunately the app is slowly deteriorating and getting buggier, so I'm just enjoying the notification feature for now until it officially dies.

Comment: @CodyGray what if the interactions are fine but you just dont care about any other interctions that happen on your question ? maybe question is old and resolved and still getting buch of "thank you" coments

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez A bunch of "thank you" comments are not "fine". While we would never punish a user for leaving them, we still want to clean up those noisy comments for the benefit of future viewers. So, those should still be flagged.

Comment: Cody and where did I say they are fine ? I actually mention them as a reason to stop notifications

Answer (score 18):

At the moment, the only recourse one has is to raise a custom flag, explaining that a user is constantly harassing you in comments, which you have done.

Moderators have the ability to apply a comment lock on posts, and if 30 days isn't enough for you, there is practically no limit on the duration.

Comment: Thanks, Samuel. I saw [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375410/disabling-notifications-for-a-question-its-10-years-old) that mentions a second scenario where this "unfollow" feature would be useful. If you read the comments under the question, it seems to have lost steam without an official resolution from a mod because it didn't have the `[feature-request]` tag. However, the accepted answer has **+71** points, and states that the only viable solution is if an "unfollow" option existed. Sounds like it would be helpful to more people than just me! :)

Comment: In this particular case, I think this user is the real problem, and it's important that they actually get feedback about how problematic their behaviour is. One user who keeps behaving like that can be big demotivator for lots of question answerers.

Comment: The user already got feedback.