# Why don't we have an Unfollow option on answers stop sending notifications of comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I have posted a valid answer on a question, but the author of the question continues to come back with comments and refuses to try my solution.  The answer is valid, but this person does not properly understand the ramifications of what they are doing and I can’t educate them in the inner workings of [OAuth 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0) in a question on Stack overflow.  I have tried as we are now up to around 10 comments.  As well as several edits on my initial answer.

Basically this question has become a vampire and is sucking the life out of me.

I don't want to delete the answer and all my comments in hopes they may read them again and understand what I am trying to tell them. So I would like to stop receiving all the notifications on this question.   I I know I could just ignore them, but...

I am not following it, but because I have an answer and comments I am by default following it I guess.

[image]

Why don't we have a way of stopping notifications on a single question or a single answer?

Comment: If it's your answer, then you are automatically opted in to receiving comments. This is because comments are *supposed* to be used to ask clarification questions and suggest improvements to the answer. If there are inappropriate comments being left, please flag them for moderator attention. If someone is *repeatedly* pestering you with invalid or inappropriate comments, then please raise a custom moderator flag *on the answer*, explain the situation in as much detail as you can (remembering mods can see deleted comments), and one of us will address it with the source of the problem.

Comment: @CodyGray there not inappropriate they are just insistent and persistent.   The person seams desperate  If i had time I would write them a full working example but its not what they want they want to do something that is not possible by design.

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375410/disabling-notifications-for-a-question-its-10-years-old). I'd say it's a dupe, despite the superficial differences.

Comment: [Or this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402420/do-we-need-a-functionality-to-mute-or-unfollow-a-comment-thread?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: While i understand that you agree to notifications when you write the answer I still feel that someone should have the option to disable it on a answer by answer basis.

Comment: Asking the same question over and over is essentially pestering. There's no reason for it. If you aren't going to expand the answer in response to the comments, then there's really no reason to let those comments continue to exist. You getting a notification is helpful, because then you can flag them for removal.

Comment: The second one is a good find, @yivi. Incidentally, I still agree with [my original comment there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402420/do-we-need-a-functionality-to-mute-or-unfollow-a-comment-thread?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment804832_402420).

Comment: @DaImTo from how you describe it, it looks like the user needs to have a chat with a mod for pestering you with requests you are unwilling to fulfill right now. After all, it made you uncomfortable enough to write a meta post - maybe it's worth a custom flag after all?

Comment: @CodyGray I flagged it.   I leave it to the mods to figure out what to do with it then.   This is the first time i have had this type of experience.  I do feel bad for the author they seem confused and frustrated.

Comment: I guess you mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68151882) in which case, they _aren't_ pestering you, they are _responding_ to you, if you want them to stop commenting, then _you_ stop commenting

Comment: an off-note from reading through the Q&A that Nick linked above is that, well, yeah, you didn't answer *their* question per se (can't blame you, though, they seem to be indeed confused on how OAuth works) as they really tried to use an access token issued client-side to obtain the refresh token from it using the PHP library, and the comment chain not look like pestering after all (just another one who got locked into doing X so badly, they refuse to understand that Y might be the solution).

Comment: "*Basically this question has become a vampire and is sucking the life out of me.*" the thing with help vampires is that they only suck the life out of you as long as you let them. Don't answer and they eventually go away. Feel free to flag the comments asking for unrelated things as "No longer needed", as well. If you feel the need to communicate, just direct them to post a new question. Something like "Please post a new question about X, so it can be answered properly, rather than in the comments." and leave it at that.

Comment: *Vampire*? It sounds more like [a *chameleon*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: @PeterMortensen more like a vampire chameleon...